# waitForQualityGate with parameters

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

As per waitForQualityGate documentation - https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/sonar/ we can pass following parameters to it -

```
abortPipeline
    Type: boolean
credentialsId (optional)
    Type: String
```

But when I pass the parameters like waitForQualityGate (false, "sonar") I get following error in Jenkins- 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [false, sonar]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use labels to define parameters:

```
waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: false, credentialsId: 'sonar'
```

Comment: Thanks @agabrys for the answer. I tried the syntax you suggested but now I am getting below error

Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {abortPipeline={abortPipeline=false, credentialsId=sonar}} for WaitForQualityGateStep(abortPipeline: boolean)

Comment: Please add your `Jenkinsfile` code to the question.